# Generating flow path using r.drain from rgrass

Tags: r, grass-gis, flow, rgrass7

I need to generate the flow path using r.drain from the rgrass7 package in RStudio.

I am new to GRASS GIS and prefer to use the R package instead. I want to generate a flow path from a grid cell.

**General Question:** For a matrix of `10*10` dimension, how to find the flow path from a given cell (not coordinate system) using GRASS GIS in R.
(https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.drain.html)

**Problem:** Once I converted the matrix to raster, the GRASS GIS is showing an error, by stating doesn't understand S4. I do not want to use raster data; I want matrix to represent the grid cells. So that, I will generate flow path form a given grid cell - trace the lowest point from the a target cell.

```
rs_grass <- writeRAST(as(rs, "SpatialGridDataFrame"), "test_rs", overwrite = T)

# GRASS GIS started from R as initGRASS()

initGRASS(gisBase = "C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 7.4.2", override = T, gisDbase = "rgrass7_TEMP")
execGRASS("g.list", parameters = list(type = "vector"))
rs_grass <- writeRAST(as(rs, "SpatialGridDataFrame"), "test_rs", overwrite = T)
execGRASS("g.region", parameters = list(vector="rs_grass", align="modis_avg@modis"))
execGRASS("v.to.rast", parameters = list(input = "rs_grass",
                                         output="rs_grass", use="cat", label_column="navn"))
```

Other case: Works - But has limitation for my work. I want this result from grass7

I used raster package in r - to find flow path from a grid cell. 
But I want to do it in GRASS GIS in R using rgrass7 - it has more flexibility for my work.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(14,5,7,9,6,14,13,12,6,8,8), b = c(9,10,10,13,7,6,7,5,9,10,11),c = c(6,8,14,15,14,12,9,5,12,14,10),
             d = c(5,8,4,13,7,5,6,9,13,10,10),e = c(13,13,10,7,9,7,10,3,13,6,11),f = c(14,15,13,7,9,13,11,14,12,12,13),g = c(6,11,9,12,13,12,5,11,8,4,6),
             h = c(15,13,14,9,7,13,14,12,4,11,11),i = c(13,15,7,8,7,11,13,8,11,7,11),
             j = c(7,9,12,15,5,7,7,5,6,15,5),k = c(14,9,6,9,9,12,15,13,14,12,7))
rs <- raster(as.matrix(df),  xmn=1, xmx=9, ymn=1, ymx=6, crs="+init=epsg:27200" )
fd <- terrain(rs, opt = "flowdir")
flowPath(fd, 49)
```

Comment: Please show as much of your code as possible, by cut and paste into your question, as well as the error message and where it occurs.